# What is the current cap for the US IRS FEIE?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, foreign-income

According to https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/figuring-the-foreign-earned-income-exclusion, dated 2 October 2017, the 2015 cap for Foreign Earned Income Exclusion was $100,800.  How can I find out the 2017 and 2018 caps?

Comment: I won't claim to understand it but it looks like it is tied to the "Chained Consumer Price Index For All Urban Consumers (C-CPI-U)"  One unknown is how Trump's tax changes will affect this.  Here's the rabbit hole I went down: http://premieroffshore.com/foreign-earned-income-exclusion-2018/  ----  https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/911  --- https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1 (section f 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: For taxable years beginning in 2017 or 2018, the caps are $102,100 and $104,100 respectively.  Source was https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-drop/rp-17-58.pdf, Section 3.34.

The FEIE is one of many IRS figures that changes annually based on a complicated inflation calculation.  The IRS publishes a list of the changed values near the end of each year.  In October when they published this, the tax code changes were still in progress, and the IRS pub states *"To the extent amendments to the Code are enacted for 2018 after October 19,
2017, taxpayers should consult additional guidance to determine whether these
adjustments remain applicable for 2018."*  I imagine that nobody updated the main link that turns up in most google searches, thus my difficulty finding the answer to the question.

Thanks to @kweinert.

Comment: [ir-2018-94 and rp-2018-18 (apparently only in IRB, I couldn't find a separate file) updates ir-2017-178 and rp-2017-58](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/inflation-adjustments-under-recently-enacted-tax-law) changing FEIE for 2018 to $103,900.